# Serialize a PHP object (Doctrine Query)

Tags: php, serialization, doctrine-query

I'm trying to serialize a Doctrine_query object in Symfony :

```
var_dump(serialize($this->pager->getQuery()));
```

The result is :

```
string(2) "N;"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Obvious question: What does `var_dump($this->pager->getQuery());` give?

Comment: The result of `$this->pager->getQuery()` is null...  So that's what's being serialized...

Comment: I tried "print_r($this->pager->getQuery())" and I get a big ouput beginning with "Doctrine_Query Object"... with many *RECURSION*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not serialize *every* object in PHP. Objects themselves - by implementing the [`Serializeable` interface <sup>**PHP Manual**</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php) - can protect themselves from being serialized for example.

They return a `NULL` value then (or don't return anything which is then `NULL` in PHP). And that's exactly the contents of your serialized string: a serialized `NULL` (`N;`).

And there are even some build-in classes that go even further than that. But it applies as well to user-defined classes and build-in classes: Some of them are not available for serialization.

---

One example of a built-in class that can not be serialized in PHP is `DOMDocument`, however it is possible to add the functionality as the following question demonstrates:

- [How to serialize/save a DOMElement in $_SESSION?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398147/how-to-serialize-save-a-domelement-in-session).