# How to serialize/save a DOMElement in $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session, dom, serialization

I'm pretty new to PHP, DOM, and the PHP DOM implementation.  What I'm trying to do is save the root element of the `DOMDocument` in a `$_SESSION` variable so I can access it and modify it on subsequent page loads.

But I get an error in PHP when using `$_SESSION` to save state of DOMElement:

> Warning: DOMNode::appendChild() [domnode.appendchild]: Couldn't fetch DOMElement

I have read that a PHP DOMDocument object cannot be saved to `$_SESSION` natively. However it can be saved by saving the serialization of the DOMDocument (e.g. `$_SESSION['dom'] = $dom->saveXML()`).

I don't know if the same holds true for saving a `DOMElement` to a `$_SESSION` variable as well, but that's what I was trying.  My reason for wanting to do this is to use an extended class of DOMElement with one additional property.  I was hoping that by saving the root DOMElement in $_SESSION that I could later retrieve the element and modify this additional property and perform a test like, if (additionalProperty === false) { do something; }.  I've also read that by saving a DOMDocument, and later retrieving it, all elements are returned as objects from native DOM classes. That is to say, even if I used an extended class to create elements, the property that I subsequently need will not be accessible, because the variable holding reference to the extended-class object has gone out of scope--which is why I'm trying this other thing.  I tried using the extended class (not included below) first, but got errors...so I reverted to using a DOMElement object to see if that was the problem, but I'm still getting the same errors.  Here's the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

$rootTag = 'root';
$doc = new DOMDocument;

if (!isset($_SESSION[$rootTag])) {
    $_SESSION[$rootTag] = new DOMElement($rootTag);
}

$root = $doc->appendChild($_SESSION[$rootTag]);
//$root = $doc->appendChild($doc->importNode($_SESSION[$rootTag], true));

$child = new DOMElement('child_element');
$n = $root->appendChild($child);

$ct = 0;
foreach ($root->childNodes as $ch) echo '<br/>'.$ch->tagName.' '.++$ct;

$_SESSION[$rootTag] = $doc->documentElement;
?>
```

This code gives the following errors (depending on whether I use appendChild directly or the commented line of code using importNode):

`Warning: DOMNode::appendChild() [domnode.appendchild]: Couldn't fetch DOMElement in C:\Program Files\wamp_server_2.2\www\test2.php on line 11`

`Warning: DOMDocument::importNode() [domdocument.importnode]: Couldn't fetch DOMElement in C:\Program Files\wamp_server_2.2\www\test2.php on line 12`

I have several questions. First, what is causing this error and how do I fix it?  Also, if what I'm trying to do isn't possible, then how can I accomplish my general objective of saving the 'state' of a DOM tree while using a custom property for each element? Note that the additional property is only used in the program and is not an attribute to be saved in the XML file.  Also, I can't just save the DOM back to file each time, because the DOMDocument, after a modification, may not be valid according to a schema I'm using until later when additional modificaitons/additions have been performed to the DOMDocument.  That's why I need to save a temporarily invalid DOMDocument.  Thanks for any advice!

EDITED:
After trying hakre's solution, the code worked.  Then I moved on to trying to use an extended class of DOMElement, and, as I suspected, it did not work. Here's the new code:

```
<?php
session_start();
//$_SESSION = array();
$rootTag = 'root';
$doc = new DOMDocument;

if (!isset($_SESSION[$rootTag])) {
    $root = new FreezableDOMElement($rootTag);
    $doc->appendChild($root);
} else {
    $doc->loadXML($_SESSION[$rootTag]);
    $root = $doc->documentElement;
}

$child = new FreezableDOMElement('child_element');
$n = $root->appendChild($child);

$ct = 0;
foreach ($root->childNodes as $ch) {
    $frozen = $ch->frozen ? 'is frozen' : 'is not frozen';
    echo '<br/>'.$ch->tagName.' '.++$ct.': '.$frozen;
    //echo '<br/>'.$ch->tagName.' '.++$ct;
}

$_SESSION[$rootTag] = $doc->saveXML();

/**********************************************************************************
 * FreezableDOMElement class
 *********************************************************************************/
class FreezableDOMElement extends DOMElement {
    public $frozen; // boolean value

    public function __construct($name) {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->frozen = false;
    }
}
?>
```

It gives me the error `Undefined property: DOMElement::$frozen`.  Like I mentioned in my original post, after `saveXML` and `loadXML`, an element originally instantiated with `FreezableDOMElement` is returning type `DOMElement` which is why the `frozen` property is not recognized.  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not store a `DOMElement` object inside `$_SESSION`. It will work at first, but with the next request, it will be unset because it can not be serialized.

That's the same like for `DOMDocument` as you write about in your question.

Store it as XML instead or encapsulate the serialization mechanism.

You are basically facing three problems here:

- Serialize the `DOMDocument` (you do this to)
- Serialize the `FreezableDOMElement` (you do this to)
- Keep the private member `FreezableDOMElement::$frozen` with the document.

As written, serialization is not available out of the box. Additionally, `DOMDocument` does not persist your `FreezableDOMElement` even w/o serialization. The following example demonstrates that the instance is not automatically kept, the default value `FALSE` is returned ([Demo](http://codepad.org/txXd6WB7)):

```
class FreezableDOMElement extends DOMElement
{
    private $frozen = FALSE;

    public function getFrozen()
    {
        return $this->frozen;
    }

    public function setFrozen($frozen)
    {
        $this->frozen = (bool)$frozen;
    }
}

class FreezableDOMDocument extends DOMDocument
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'FreezableDOMElement');
    }
}

$doc = new FreezableDOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root><child></child></root>');

# own objects do not persist
$doc->documentElement->setFrozen(TRUE);
printf("Element is frozen (should): %d\n", $doc->documentElement->getFrozen()); # it is not (0)
```

As PHP does not so far support `setUserData` (DOM Level 3), one way could be to store the additional information inside a namespaced attribute with the element. This can also be serialized by creating the XML string when serializing the object and loading it when unserializing (see [`Serializable`](http://php.net/Serializable)). This then solves all three problems ([Demo](http://codepad.org/w4dZn6gW)):

```
class FreezableDOMElement extends DOMElement
{
    public function getFrozen()
    {
        return $this->getFrozenAttribute()->nodeValue === 'YES';
    }

    public function setFrozen($frozen)
    {
        $this->getFrozenAttribute()->nodeValue = $frozen ? 'YES' : 'NO';
    }

    private function getFrozenAttribute()
    {
        return $this->getSerializedAttribute('frozen');
    }

    protected function getSerializedAttribute($localName)
    {
        $namespaceURI = FreezableDOMDocument::NS_URI;
        $prefix = FreezableDOMDocument::NS_PREFIX;

        if ($this->hasAttributeNS($namespaceURI, $localName)) {
            $attrib = $this->getAttributeNodeNS($namespaceURI, $localName);
        } else {
            $this->ownerDocument->documentElement->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:' . $prefix, $namespaceURI);
            $attrib = $this->ownerDocument->createAttributeNS($namespaceURI, $prefix . ':' . $localName);
            $attrib = $this->appendChild($attrib);
        }
        return $attrib;
    }
}

class FreezableDOMDocument extends DOMDocument implements Serializable
{
    const NS_URI = '/frozen.org/freeze/2';
    const NS_PREFIX = 'freeze';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->registerNodeClasses();
    }

    private function registerNodeClasses()
    {
        $this->registerNodeClass('DOMElement', 'FreezableDOMElement');
    }

    /**
     * @return DOMNodeList
     */
    private function getNodes()
    {
        $xp = new DOMXPath($this);
        return $xp->query('//*');
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return parent::saveXML();
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->registerNodeClasses();
        $this->loadXML($serialized);
    }

    public function saveBareXML()
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML(parent::saveXML());
        $xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
        foreach ($xp->query('//@*[namespace-uri()=\'' . self::NS_URI . '\']') as $attr) {
            /* @var $attr DOMAttr */
            $attr->parentNode->removeAttributeNode($attr);
        }
        $doc->documentElement->removeAttributeNS(self::NS_URI, self::NS_PREFIX);
        return $doc->saveXML();
    }

    public function saveXMLDirect()
    {
        return parent::saveXML();
    }
}

$doc = new FreezableDOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root><child></child></root>');
$doc->documentElement->setFrozen(TRUE);
$child = $doc->getElementsByTagName('child')->item(0);
$child->setFrozen(TRUE);

echo "Plain XML:\n", $doc->saveXML(), "\n";
echo "Bare XML:\n", $doc->saveBareXML(), "\n";

$serialized = serialize($doc);

echo "Serialized:\n", $serialized, "\n";

$newDoc = unserialize($serialized);

printf("Document Element is frozen (should be): %s\n", $newDoc->documentElement->getFrozen() ? 'YES' : 'NO');
printf("Child Element is frozen (should be): %s\n", $newDoc->getElementsByTagName('child')->item(0)->getFrozen() ? 'YES' : 'NO');
```

It's not really feature complete but a working demo. It's possible to obtain the full XML without the additional "freeze" data.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I am going to try implementing the solution you describe. However, it sounds like I will probably still run into the problem of not having extended class properties accessible when the XML string is reloaded into a DOMDocument, right?

Comment: @neizan: About what do you speak here? If you take care of serialization your own, you should have all possibilities you're looking for. It's just that normally serializing `DOMDocument` makes no sense, as XML is a form of serialization already.

Comment: Right, when I said serialization I was referring to using the `saveXML` method, sorry for the confusion. Please take a look at the additional sample code I've just posted which tries to do what you say.  It worked using a `DOMElement`, but not with the extended class `FreezableDOMElement`.

Comment: How should just extending from DOMElement allow serialization (as PHP session)? Probably if you tell what you want to do, it's easier to suggest you something working.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but let me explain myself a little better. Doing what you said worked: create `DOMDocument` and add elements, then use `DOMDocuemnt::saveXML` to save it to `$_SESSION`, then on next page load, `DOMDocument::loadXML` (from `$_SESSION`). Great. Now, I'm trying to use an extended class, `FreezableDOMElement`, which has the property `$frozen`. However, on subsequent page loads, when `loadXML` is called, the elements in the document are not of type `FreezableDOMElement`, but rather `DOMElement`. I figured this would happen. My question is how do I get around this?

Comment: By telling your DOMDocument which DOMElement class you want to use: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.registernodeclass.php

Comment: I did this, and it avoids the error, but the property value is lost after a page load and a call to `loadXML`. For example, if I do `$el = new FreezableDOMElement()`, `$el->frozen = true`, then `saveXML`, later `loadXML`, and retrieve `$el`, then `$el->frozen` returns `false`. So it appears `registernodeclass` is used to add custom methods but that it doesn't mean property values will be retained. Am I wrong? Any other suggestions? Thanks for staying with me!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10750/discussion-between-hakre-and-neizan)